# My average function is returning slightly wrong answer

Tags: python, csv, average

I'm computing the average of the numbers in one column of a csv file. It's working, but my answer is so slightly off from what it needs to be. For example; one filter I enter returns 49.93 when it should be 49.94. Another is 23.05 when it should be 23.17. And one is 37.02 instead of 37.21. I'm going crazy trying to figure out how to fix this. Also, I originally wanted `lenl = 0.0` but when I do that it won't calculate because you can't divide by zero, even though the counter should still be going up? Please help

```
import csv

        
date_index = 0
temp_index = 2

def average_temperature(weather, filter):
    thefile = csv_reader("Temperatures.csv")
    suml = 0.0
    lenl = 1.0
    for row in thefile:
        if filter in row[date_index]:
            suml += float(row[temp_index])
            lenl += 1.0
        avg = suml / lenl
    return avg
```

Comment: Makes `lenl = 0` unindent the avg calculation to be once at the end, and then do `avg = suml / (lenl or 1)` which will make `(0.0/0.0)` change to `(0.0/1)`

Comment: Initialize the len to zero, not one.

Comment: There's no need for `lenl` to be a float, it's naturally an integer and the math works with integers just fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. For debugging help, you need to make a [mre] including complete but minimal code (to start, the call to `average_temperature()`) and example input. It looks like the CSV is not actually relevant to the problem except that that's where the data is, in which case, remove the [tag:csv] tag. For more tips, see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `len` to `0`. Take `avg` calculation outside the loop.
You can add a `try-except` block in the end to catch the `0/0` cases and deal with them-

```
import csv

        
date_index = 0
temp_index = 2

def average_temperature(weather, filter):
    thefile = csv_reader("Temperatures.csv")
    suml = 0
    lenl = 0
    for row in thefile:
        if filter in row[date_index]:
            suml += row[temp_index]
            lenl += 1
    try:
        avg = suml / lenl
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        avg = 0

    return avg
```

Comment: Try/except is the usual recommended method in Python, EAFP vs. LBYL.  But in this particular case it seems really simple to test for zero explicitly: `avg = suml / lenl if lenl else 0`.